Getting 'geocoder undefined' error when using Leaflet Control Geocoder with Laravel Filament
I'm developing a Laravel application using the Filament admin panel. I'm trying to integrate Leaflet and the Leaflet Control Geocoder plugin to display a map and geocode addresses.
However, I'm encountering a "geocoder undefined" error in the console when I try to use L.Control.Geocoder.
Here's the relevant part of my Blade template:
<!-- Blade Template -->
<x-filament::page>
    <!-- Head section -->
    <head>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Select2 JS and CSS -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css"/>

        <!-- Leaflet JS and CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>

        <!-- Leaflet Control Geocoder JS and CSS -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css"/>
    </head>

    <!-- Body content -->
    <div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            // Initialize the map
            var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
            var marker;

            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

            // Attempt to use the geocoder
            console.log(L.Control.Geocoder); // Outputs undefined

            if (L.Control.Geocoder) {
                var geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim();
                // Additional code...
            } else {
                alert('Geocoder plugin could not be loaded.');
            }
        });
    </script>
</x-filament::page>

I have included all the necessary scripts and styles in the head section, and they are in the correct order.
I suspect that the issue might be related to how Laravel Filament handles asset loading and rendering.
What I've tried:
Ensured that scripts and styles are included in the correct order.
Used Filament's asset management methods like getHeaderScripts() and getHeaderStyles() in the page class.
Checked the browser console for any errors related to script loading.
Attempted to log L.Control.Geocoder to see if it's defined.
Despite these efforts, the problem persists. The console logs undefined for L.Control.Geocoder, and the geocoder functionality doesn't work.
Question:
How can I properly include and use the Leaflet Control Geocoder plugin in a Laravel Filament application? Is there a specific way to load external scripts and styles when using Filament?
